# Docker on Mac/OSX: How to correct typo in settings?

Tags: docker, mac

I made a typo in the configuration specifying an insecure registry in the graphical UI as

```
192.1.1.1;5000
```

The semicolon should be a colon of course :-(

When starting Docker with the graphical UI there is an error message and the Docker graphical UI terminates. I cannot make any changed to the Docker configuration any more.

How to correct my typo?

Is there a `daemon.json` file on the Mac/OSX and how can I find it? Can I edit the permanent Docker settings there?

Answer (score 0):

many json files for  the configuration are stored in this path :

```
/Users/<USERNAME>/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker
```